# Communities User language option other than english

Tags: community, administration, customer-community

In dev. sandbox when creating a community user, I am able to select either German or English.

[image: sandbox screenshot]

In our production, the only option is english, is there something I need to enable? The person who setup community in dev. is not available so couldn't ask him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Setup-> Company Profile-> Language settings and add new language.

[image]